# How to transform a hotstring into a multiline text?

Tags: escaping, autohotkey

I am trying to have `errnil` output

```
if err != nil {<Enter>
```

Where `<Enter>` is the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key (or <kbd>Return</kbd> on some keyboards).

I tried all kind of incantations to ensure that the text up until <kbd>Enter</kbd> is escaped but I get just pieces of the string (usually without the `!=` and `{` part).

The latest example is

```
:*:errnil::if err `!= nil `{{Enter}
```

which generates (with a space at the end)

```
if err  nil
```

(the backtick was an attempt to [escape the character](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/EscapeChar.htm) but with our without it the result is the same)

**How should I escape `!=` and `{` and add a newline at the end?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **!**, **{**, **}**, **#** etc, are [special keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#keynames) that must be enclosed in braces to be sent.
- To start a new line you can include the linefeed character or a carriage return and linefeed pair.

  ```
  :*:errnil::if err {!}= nil `n

  :*:braces::{{}{}}`n
  ```

See also [continuation section](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#continuation).

Comment: Thanks, would you know how to escape the `{`? (or where the docs discuss this, the only link I found is the one I provided in the question)

Comment: Even better: use the [`T` option](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#T) for the hotstring instead of escaping.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, below script should work fine. :)

```
:*:errnil::
SendRaw, if err != nil {
Send, {Enter}
return
```